# Altium Designer 10 - How to make track connected to pad rule

Tags: altium

Does anybody know how to make a rule in Altium Designer on a track connected to a pad? Now I'm able to make rule on pad and on track separately, but sometimes I need to make a rule on a track only in the point in which the track is connected to a pad, and I don't know how to do it.

Comment: Can you explain better what you want to achieve? It sounds like you are talking about neck downs. That is specifying small lengths of a trace to be thinner where it approaches the pad of a component.

Comment: No i don't want a neck down. I need to set different rule on track attached to pads. For example: I've a clearance rule between a pair of tracks of 50mil but only in point in which touches pad I want a clearance of 30mil because clearance of pads is 30mil. Hope to explain myself better..sorry for my English.

Comment: I know that is possible to achieve this goal with rooms, already done. Does exist another way to do that?